# where to save images uploaded via POST and how to send that image via GET

Tags: node.js, express, http, multer

My problem seems common but with a variety of use cases, I couldn't find the exact answer

**the idea**:

user will upload an image from front-end, every upload should create a json entry in database like:

```
{
    id: number,
    description: string,
    image_url: string //important, this should be the image url
}
```

where do I save these images such that I can have an `image_url` so whenever someone puts the url in browser that image is seen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can save your images in a folder and then serve its files using something like this:

```
app.use('/images', express.static('images'))
```

and image links would be like `your-domain.com/images/IMAGE_NAME`.
you can read more [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)